# JMeter to execute JUnit tests based on Cucumber (java)

Tags: java, jmeter, cucumber

I am a beginner at automation testing.

I am trying to execute tests that were written in java using Selenium WebDriver, Cucumber with Gherkin annotations in JMeter.

When I run my tests without JMeter, I just use the opportunity to run them as Junit test using the runner class (in Eclipse).

[image: Runner class]

To run my tests in JMeter, I created a jar file, uploaded it to Junit sub-folder, all dependencies-jars were uploaded to lib sub-folder.

I tried to create a JUnit request in JMeter, but it didn't help as when we use Cucumber, we don't mark methods with @Test. I have just an empty constructor for my Runner class (as you can see from the picture above).

I tried to add my jar to Test Plan and create an instance of my class in BeanShell, but it is not executed as JUnit tests.

[image: JMeter - screen1]

[image: JMeter - screen2]

My question is how to run java test scripts that were written based on Cucumber with Gherkin (based on Selenium WebDriver)?

Maybe I have to use other Samplers...

Any examples are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to run another class, in particular [`io.cucumber.core.cli.Main`](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/cli/Main.java), something like:

```
io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(new String[]{
        "--glue",
        "the package which contains the glue classes", 
        "/your/feature/file"});
```

Check out [Running Cucumber -> From the command line](https://docs.cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#from-the-command-line) for all the available arguments explained. By the way, you can use [OS Process Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) for this, it will be way easier.

---

Depending on what you're trying to achieve it might be faster and easier to [convert your Selenium tests into "native" JMeter ones](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-convert-selenium-scripts-jmx-converter) as if you're going to use your Selenium tests for creating the load it will require immense hardware resources and you won't get performance metrics on the HTTP protocol level.